# Can I use -cp argument twice when executing Java?

Tags: java, linux, jar

I am trying to run a Java application which has many dependencies. In the past I have use the following command to launch the application

```
java -cp "program.jar:jar1.jar:jar2.jar:jar3.jar:[...]" program
```

However as the list of dependencies have grown, I have moved them into an arguments file, the contents of this file are:

```
-cp "\
program.jar:\
jar1.jar:\
jar2.jar:\
jar3.jar:\
[...]"
```

And I am running the application with

```
java @arguments-file program
```

Everything up to this point works fine.

Sometimes I end up with beta versions of program.jar, they share all of the same dependencies, but program.jar is renamed `program-beta.jar`.

So to run the jar the following command would be used

```
java -cp "program-beta.jar:jar1.jar:jar2.jar:jar3.jar:[...]" program
```

or more specifically, I would use an environment variable, so that the same script can be used, and the variable would be set to either program.jar, or program-beta.jar, depending on the circumstance

```
java -cp "$PROGRAM_JAR:jar1.jar:jar2.jar:jar3.jar:[...]" program
```

Now that I am using an arguments file I was hoping to be able to be able to do something like:

```
java -cp "$PROGRAM_JAR" @arguments-file program
```

However using `-cp` twice causes one of the two to be ignored, resulting in a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exception.

Is there any way around this that allows me to specify one jar file by name, but abstract away all of the others so that my `java` command isn't thousands of characters?

This will be running entirely on Linux, so any command line "magic", such as using `grep` is fine, so long as the resulting code is easily readable

Comment: Why not use Maven or ANT to define your application dependencies?

Comment: How about making a fat jar, or just put your jars in a single folder and use that folder as the class path?

Comment: I like the suggestion by @Sweeper – since you can't point `-cp` at multiple locations, work with that constraint and just put all the things in one location.

Comment: At the moment the jars are technically in one location, however that location has sub-folders within it, so we have some jars in `jars` and others in `jars/folder1`, `jars/folder2`, etc. Since `jars/*` doesn't traverse into sub-directories, each time we add a folder we need to change the script, and my hope with the script was to keep it as short as possible, and require almost no changes, even when a sub-folder is added.

Answer (score -1):

You could just write two bash scripts `production.sh` and `beta.sh` that contain a reference on `program.jar` and `program-beta.jar`, respectively.

Also, the classpath can contain wildcards ([see man-page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html)), so if you can ensure that on disk exists only one of the two versions, you can write it like this:

```
java -cp "program*:jar1.jar:jar2.jar:jar3.jar:[...]"
```

In the long term, you might think about building/running it with Maven or Gradle, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately neither will work, the system that I am working on is a legacy one, and it has a bunch of silly restrictions, for example there can be only one shell script, and both program.jar and program-beta.jar might exist at the same time. 

As for your Maven suggestion, I would be open to that, as we already use Maven for building, but it's and extremely basic pom file. Is there a way to add external references (without packaging them into a fat jar) with Maven?

Comment: Can you just use an environment variable for your jar (say `$PRG`) and then concatenate `$PRG` and the rest of the classpath in your script?

Comment: You have misunderstood how wildcards in classpaths work.  They are not the same as file globbing wildcards.  The asterisk character must be the only character following a directory separator.  `somedir/*` is okay, but `somedir/prefix*` is not.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right about that.